# Apache Camel - Transferir un archivo por MQ Websphere

Tags: apache, websphere

quiero transmitir un archivo de un servidor a otro por medio de Camel.
Cuando leo el archivo y lo envio a MQ lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
<route id="FileToMQ">
   <from uri="file:/home/walter/Pru/Entrada"/>
   <to uri="wmq:ALPHA.QREMOTE.NOVEDADES.BETA?grouping=true&amp;groupMessageSize=2097152"/>        
</route>
```

y luego otra ruta para recibir el mensaje de MQ y guardarlo nuevamente en una carpeta.

```
<route id="MQtoFile">
    <from uri="wmq2:ALPHA.ALL.NOVEDADES.BETA?grouping=true"/>
    <to uri="file:/home/walter/Pru/Salida"/>
</route>
```

El problema es que un archivo se genera en /home/walter/Pru/Salida pero con un nombre como "ID-servidor3-49815-1518022285419-197-1"

Como debería hacer para no perder el nombre del archivo y que en la salida se genere el mismo nombre del archivo de entrada?

Muchas gracias,

Walter

Answer (score 0):

No deberías usar el parámetro `grouping=true`.

Lo que estás haciendo es agregar diferentes ficheros en uno y eso implica que el resultado es un nuevo mensaje Camel, perdiendo los headers originales.

Comment: Hola Jordi, muchas gracias.
En realidad el grouping lo que hace es dividir el archivo cuando llega al tamaño definido que es 2097152.
Lo solucioné primero Zipeando el archivo (al enviarlo) y luego descompactandolo al recibirlo. Por ahi no es la mejor solución pero en principio funciona. Lo otro que vi se puede hacer es mandar en algunos de los headers de de MQ el nombre de archivo y al recibirlo renombrar el camelname por este nombre del MQ. Tambien otro parche...
Saludos!